# Find the remainder $R$ of $(1^2+1)(2^2+1)...(p^2+1)$ divided by $p$

Tags: number-theory

> Find the remainder $R$ of $(1^2+1)(2^2+1)...(p^2+1)$ divided by $p$, with $p$ being a prime number greater than $3$.

For $p \equiv 1 \mod 4$, there exists an integer $j$ such that $p\mid j^2+1$ (since $-1$ is a quadratic residue of $p$), therefore $R=0$.

For $p \equiv 3 \mod 4$, how can we find $R$? Does $R$ depend on the value of $p$?

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: I have proved that if $p \equiv 1 \pmod 4$, then $x=0$, but nothing more. I claim also, that $x=4$ if $p \equiv 3 \pmod 4$ Can you please post a solution?

Comment: A numerical experiment suggests that, unless $p=2$ or $p=3$, the answer is $0$ if $p\equiv1\pmod4$ and $4$ otherwise. I don't know how to prove it, though.

Comment: Are all the coefficients of $x^k$ in $(x+1^2)(x+2^2)\cdots(x+({p-1\over2})^2)$ multiples of $p$ ?

Answer (score 8):

If $p=2$ or $p\equiv 1\pmod{4}$, then $R$ is obviously $0$ because $-1$ is a quadratic residue modulo $p$.  We assume from now on that $p\equiv 3\pmod{4}$.

Let $f(x)$ denote the polynomial $x^p-x$ over the Galois field $K=\operatorname{GF}(p)$.  Note that $f$ factorizes into
$$f(x)=\prod_{t\in K}(x-t).$$
Let $E$ be the extension $K[X]/(X^2+1)$ of $K$, which is just the Galois field $\operatorname{GF}(p^2)$.  (This is where we use the assumption that $p\equiv 3\pmod{4}$, since $X^2+1$ is irreducible over $K$.)  Write $i$ for the image of $X$ under the canonical projection $K[X]\to K[X]/(X^2+1)=E$.

Now, we have
$$R=\prod_{k=1}^p(k^2+1)=\prod_{k=1}^p(i-k)(-i-k)=\left(\prod_{k=1}^p(i-k)\right)\left(\prod_{k=1}^p(-i-k)\right).$$
By the definition of $f$, we get
$$R=f(i)f(-i)=\left(i^p-i\right)\left((-i)^p-(-i)\right)=\left(i^{p-1}-1\right)\left((-i)^{p-1}-1\right).$$
Since $\frac{p-1}{2}$ is odd, we have
$$R=\left((-1)^{\frac{p-1}{2}}-1\right)\left((-1)^{\frac{p-1}{2}}-1\right)=\big((-1)-1\big)^2=4.$$
This is an equality in $K$.  Translating this result back to $\Bbb{Z}$, we conclude that
$$R=\begin{cases}
0&\text{if}\ p=2 \vee p\equiv 1\pmod{4},\\
1&\text{if}\ p=3,\\
4&\text{if}\ p>3 \wedge p\equiv 3\pmod{4}.
\end{cases}$$

Answer (score 4):

We can also use the symmetric polynomials.

Let $A=(1^2+1)(2^2+1) \cdots ((p-1)^2+1)(p^2+1)$. Then, $A \equiv (1^2+1)(2^2+1) \cdots ((p-1)^2+1) \mod p$, since $p^2+1\equiv 1 \mod p$.

Consider the symmetric polynomial $\displaystyle\prod_{i=1}^{\frac{p-1}2}(1+x_i)=\sum_{j=0}^{\frac{p-1}2}e_j(x)$, where $e_j$ is the $j$-th [elementary symmetric polynomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_symmetric_polynomial).
Then $\displaystyle A\equiv(\sum_{j=0}^{\frac{p-1}2}e_j(y))^2$, where $y_i$ belongs to the set $QR:=\{1^2,\cdots,(\frac{p-1}2)^2\}$.

Now notice that $QR$ consists of roots of $x^{(p-1)/2}-1$ (over $\mathbb F_p$). So $e_j(y)$ is $(-1)^j$ times the coefficient of $x^{\frac{p-1}2-j}$ in $x^{(p-1)/2}-1$. Thus $e_0(y)=1,\,e_{(p-1)/2}(y)=(-1)^{\frac{p+1}2}$, and $e_j(y)=0$ otherwise.

Therefore $A\equiv(1+(-1)^{(p+1)/2})^2\pmod p$.

Comment: Yes thanks, but have you something easier (juniors, maybe ...)?

Answer (score 3):

If $ p $ is not $ 3 $ modulo $ 4 $ the given expression is trivially $ 0 $, so assume $ p \equiv 3 \pmod{4} $.

Consider the polynomial

$$ P(x) = \prod_k (x + k) $$

where the product is taken over all $ k $ which are quadratic residues mod $ p $ (excluding $ 0 $). First, observe that if $ r $ is a quadratic residue mod $ p $, then

$$ P(r) = \prod_k (r + k) = r^{(p-1)/2} \prod_k (1 + k r^{-1}) = \prod_k (1 + k) = P(1) = c $$

In addition, it follows by pairing each non-identity quadratic residue with its inverse that $ P(0) = 1 $. The only polynomial mod $ p $ of degree $ \leq (p-1)/2 $ which satisfies these conditions is $ (c-1) x^{(p-1)/2} + 1 $ (it's easy to check that it has the required values, and uniqueness is easy to see.) Since $ P $ has leading coefficient $ 1 $, it follows $ c = 2 $, and so $ P(1) = 2 $. The expression given in the question is $ P(1)^2 $, which is therefore always equal to $ 4 $ mod $ p $.

Answer (score 2):

Supposing $$(x-1)(x-2)...(x-(p-1))\equiv x^{p-1}\pm1\pmod{p}$$
The left-hand side is $$(x^2-1^2)(x^2-2^2)...(x^2-({p-1\over2})^2)\pmod p$$
Replace $x^2$ by $y$; and then replace $y$ by $-1$.  The left-hand side is now a square-root of your product $\pmod p$, give or take a sign.  The right-hand side is $1\pm1$.
Can you fill in the details?

Comment: Thanks, have you something easier (juniors, maybe ...)?

Answer (score 2):

Let $p$ be a prime, with $p\equiv 3\;(\text{mod}\;4)$.

**Claim:**
$$\prod_{k=1}^p (1+k^2)\equiv 4\;(\text{mod}\;p)$$
**Proof:**
\begin{align*}
\prod_{k=1}^p (1+k^2)\;(\text{mod}\;p)
&\equiv
\prod_{k=1}^{p-1} (1+k^2)\;(\text{mod}\;p)
\\[4pt]
&\equiv
\left(\prod_{k=1}^{\frac{p-1}{2}}(1+k^2)\right)^{\!\!2}\;(\text{mod}\;p)
\\[4pt]
\end{align*}

Thus, to prove the claim, it suffices to show 
$$
\prod_{k=1}^{\frac{p-1}{2}}(1+k^2)\equiv 2\;(\text{mod}\;p)
$$
Note that
$$1+1^2,1+2^2,...,1+\left({\small{\frac{p-1}{2}}}\right)^{\!2}$$
are distinct mod $p$, and are the roots of the congruence $f(x)\equiv 0\;(\text{mod}\;p)$, where
$$f(x)=(x-1)^{\frac{p-1}{2}}-1$$
Since $p\equiv 3\;(\text{mod}\;4)$, it follows that $\frac{p-1}{2}$ is odd, hence the constant term of $f$ is $-2$.$\\[4pt]$

Note that $f$ is monic, hence by Vieta's formula, since $\frac{p-1}{2}$ is odd, and the constant term of $f$ is $-2$, the product in $Z_p$ of the roots of $f$ is $2$, so we get
$$
\prod_{k=1}^{\frac{p-1}{2}}(1+k^2)\equiv 2\;(\text{mod}\;p)
$$
which proves the claim.

Thus, if $p$ is prime, with $p\equiv 3\;(\text{mod}\;4)$, we get $R\equiv 2^2\;(\text{mod}\;p)$, hence 
$$
\begin{cases}
R=4,\;\text{if}\;p > 3\\[4pt]
R=1,\;\text{if}\;p = 3\\
\end{cases}
$$

Answer (score 0):

With this script in MATHEMATICA you can check a lot

`n=10000
primes = Select[Range[n], PrimeQ[#] && NextPrime[#] == 2 + # &]
p[n_] := Product[1 + k^2, {k, 1, n}]
For [j = 1, j <= Length[primes], j++, 
 Print[primes[[j]], " ", Mod[p[primes[[j]]], primes[[j]]]]]`

What to say  about this pattern for the first bunch ?

$$
\{1,0,4,0,0,0,4,4,0,4,0,0,4,4,0,4,4,0,0,4,4,4,4,0,0,0,4,0,0,4,0,0,4,0,0,4,4,0,0,4,4,0,0,0,0,4,4,4,0,4,4,4,4,0,0,4,4,0,4,0,0,4,0,4,4,0,0,0,
   4,0,4,0,0,4,0,4,4,0,0,0,0,4,4,4,4,0,4,0,4,4,0,0,4,4,4,0,0,4,4,0,4,0,0,0,4,0,4,4,0,0,0,0,4,4,0,0,0,0,4,0,0,0,4,4,4,4,0,0,4,4,4,0,0,0,0,4
   ,4,4,0,0,0,4,4,0,4,0,0,4,4,0,4,0,4,0,0,0,4,4,4,0,4,4,4,4,4,4,0,0,4,4,4,0,0,0,0,0,4,4,4,4,4,0,0,0,4,4,0,0,0,4,4,0,4,0,0,4,4,0,0,0,0,4,4,
   0,0,\cdots \}
$$